# Jquery show if url contains

Tags: url, if-statement, show, contains

I have a simple jquery script that shows and hides div block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">'
    $(document).ready(function(){    
        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $('.show_hide').click(function(){
            $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        }); 
    });
</script>

<a class="show_hide" href="#">Show/hide</a>
<div name="gohere" class="slidingDiv">
   ...
</div>
```

It's working fine, but if the URL contains #gohere I want to automatically show this div and hide it only if `.show_hide` is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the divs ID to be gohere, then you can do:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $($(this).attr('href')).slideToggle();
});
```

since your href attribute will contain `#gohere`, the selector for the slidetoggle will end up being `#gohere`, which corelates to your divs ID.

EDIT:
for the first part of your question, you can get the current hash tag from `window.location.hash`.

```
if (window.location.hash.length > 0) {
    $(window.location.hash).show();
}
```

You should probably put some better error checking in there, but it should work.